# Temporary image on first load of page

Tags: jquery, image

i will like to load an small image temporary on the first load of the page, similar to the drag and droll image shown in this website "http://www.demodern.de/". It should show and disappear as seen in the referenced website. It may be really simple but im really struggling with it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#viewport, #header_viewport').
        scrollsync({targetSelector: '#viewport', axis : 'x'});
        $('#viewport, #inner').
        dragscrollable({dragSelector: '.dragger:first',  acceptPropagatedEvent: false});
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="main">
    <div id="viewport" class="dragger">
        <div id="base" class="dragger" style="background-          image:url('images/battery.jpg');">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post your code.  Links rarely last forever.

Comment: ok, so i finally got to comment the code, i did reduce a lot it, but the point is that viewport contains a large image (6000px aprx) that scrolls when you drag it and drop it. I would like to show a message or an image that explains the way to interact with the page. That message should only be temporary.

Comment: I have been trying this [http://plugins.jquery.com/project/flash] but it doesn´t seem to be working, i want to display the message as you open a new html (after clicking on a link), and the flash requires to add an href="" to display the message.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it. It was way simpler than i thought. just added a ready function in the head and seems to work!